# Passing value from one ViewController to another in Storyboard in SWIFT Language

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swift, ios8

I start project in Swift Language. Apps almost done. Single ViewController logics are all done. But I need to communicate with each other ViewController.

I want to pass some value from one ViewController to another ViewController. I'm using StoryBoard. I want to pass value using prepareSeague function as like Objective-C has. Is there any way to do this without using delegate-way.

Answer (score 0):

In the first view controller handle `prepareForSegue` method and provide additional values to the second  view controller, like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "someidentifier" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as MySecondViewController
        // vc.someProperty = someValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How I get / read this value in SecondViewcontroller? I need to call FirstViewController in SecondViewController. Then how to call "someProperty" in SecondViewController?